# How does a Short position impact the PnL?

Tags: portfolio, accounting, pnl

I have several activity records which include several transaction types: `buy`, `sell`, `short`, `cover`, etc.

I understand the impact of `buy` and `sell` on the Unrealized, Daily and Realized P&L of a security or Portfolio.

However, how do you deal with a `short` position in a security? Is everything just in reverse (i.e. `buy * -1`)?

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.  Below is a pretty simple example:

```
Side    Position (Shares)   Entry Price Current Price   Open PnL
Long    1000                100         90              -10,000
Short   -1000               100         90               10,000
```

You don't need the Side and Position if you are going to use -ve values for Short positions.  I just put both in for your benefit.  Having Short and a -ve Position size is redundant and/or a double negative.  Using either one to adjust your PnL formula will work.  I personally use -ve numbers for Short positions and don't use an actual Short label.